# Problem echoing this line in PHP

Tags: php, quotes, echo

I am having trouble echoing this line. Is anyone willing to help?

```
echo '<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/thread-'.$row->tid.'-1-1.html'">'.$row->subject.'</a></li>';
```

Comment: just one not wanted ' quote. can't you spot it yourself?

Comment: I think the SO syntax highlighter spotted it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your string is enclosed in [single-quotes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single), you have to close the quotes, concatenate the variables, and re-open the quotes :

```
echo '<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/thread-'
  . $row->tid
  . '-1-1.html">'
  . $row->subject
  . '</a></li>';
```

*(split over several lines to improve readability)*

Else, you could use a [double-quoted][2] string, to have variables interpolation -- escaping the double-quotes that are inside the string :

```
echo "<li><a href=\"http://stackoverflow.com/thread-{$row->tid}-1-1.html\">{$row->subject}</a></li>";
```

Comment: many thanks you made me know another ways to get the same effect.

Comment: You do not need to concatenate the variables. Echo accepts multiple parameters (echo 'hi', $name, 'welcome to site';) which is faster than concatenating the string together. not a problem when echoing one or two dozen lines. But massive performance saver when using echo on hundreds/thousands of lines.

Comment: @Dickie in fact there is nothing massive nor performance saver at all. Do not listen to lame rumors

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are mismatched.

```
....'-1-1.html">'....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

echo <<<_HTML_

<li>
    <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/thread-{$row->tid} 1-1.html">{$row->subject}</a>
</li>

_HTML_;

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are echoing one single quote too much in the middle of this part: `'-1-1.html'">'`. This single quote is currently closing the string and will result in a parse error.

If your editor is supporting syntax highlighting, you will be able to notice a difference in colour after this quote.

To solve this problem, change this your code to:

```
echo '<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/thread-'.$row->tid.'-1-1.html">'.$row->subject.'</a></li>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
?>
<li>
 <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/thread-<?=$row->tid?>-1-1.html">
   <?=$row->subject?>
 </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
echo '<li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/thread-'.$row->tid.'-1-1.html">'.$row->subject.'</a></li>';
```